# universal nodejs app starter example with react

Tags: mongodb, authentication, express, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I want to learn do **isomorphic javascript apps**.

I started with with **meteorjs** and I found all in one example with usage of mongo collections, react.js views and authentication.

[react-todos](https://github.com/meteor/react-packages/tree/devel/examples/react-todos)

From this starter I can finish many apps I want to.

Now I want to learn **alternative** to meteor app using node.js and express on backend.
Everytime I find something on github I can not even run it. I always get some package error I even do not understand and with Google I spent already dozens of hours on it. 
Next works in meteor with example above are easy for me.

But run **together**
*express, mongodb, react, react-routers and some login/signup auth* and do universal app is rocket science for me. How to start please?

Comment: You're right, firstly it's not a simple thing, and also most starter kits are out of date. It isn't rocket science but getting that setup you described isn't trivial either, so it's not just you. My starter is using redux and might confuse you because of that, but at the bottom of the readme you can see a link to a simpler version before redux: https://github.com/DominicTobias/universal-react/

Comment: After installing yours and "npm start" I get also common error with no details. 
17 error Darwin 15.0.0
18 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
19 error node v5.3.0
20 error npm  v3.3.12
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error universal-react@1.0.0-beta start: `node server`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the universal-react@1.0.0-beta start script 'node server'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed..... And for sure I have latest node and npm, some packages run ok

Comment: You can check my build https://github.com/DWboutin/Beverage